# Concurrent API post request problem in web api mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Recently i faced a major problem in concurrent api post request where 100 request at a time. Is there any option to handle the request one by one i mean one request complete then another request going to be execute?
I already used async task but no better feedback. Please give me a suggestion to solved this issue.

**Updated:** add code of my api

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/test/Create")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create([FromBody]TestModel getmodel)
    {
        Dictionary<object, object> dict = new Dictionary<object, object>();

        Int64 companyCode = 101, usercode = 10101001, a = 0;

        if (TokenInfo.TokenCheck(companyCode, usercode, getmodel.token))
        {
            using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                try
                {                        
                        MainModel model = new MainModel();
                        model.COMPID = 101;
                        model.CARDDT = carddt;
                        model.CARDYY = getyear;
                        model.PSGRNM = Convert.ToString(agent);
                        model.CARDCID = Convert.ToString(101001);
                        model.ROUTE = getmodel.route;
                        model.AGENTID = agent;
                        model.REMARKS = getmodel.remarks;
                        model.MOBNO = getmodel.mobile_No;
                        model.TICKETLTP = "Null";

                        Int64 max_cardno =
                            Convert.ToInt64(
                                await
                                    db.modelDbSet.Where(x => x.COMPID == 101 && x.CARDYY == getyear)
                                        .MaxAsync(x => x.CARDNO));

                        if (max_cardno == 0)
                        {
                            string aa = Convert.ToString(getmodel.year);
                            model.CARDNO = aa.Substring(2, 2) + "00001";
                            model.CARDID = model.COMPID + "10202" + model.CARDNO;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            model.CARDNO = Convert.ToString(max_cardno + 1);
                            model.CARDID = model.COMPID + "10202" + model.CARDNO;
                        }
                        Int64 length = Convert.ToInt64(model.CARDNO.Length);
                        if (length == 7)
                        {
                            db.modelDbSet.Add(model);
                            await db.SaveChangesAsync();                               
                            transaction.Commit();

                            dict.Add(key:"data",value:model.CARDNO);
                            dict.Add(key: "success", value: true);
                            dict.Add(key: "message", value: "Data Saved Successfully.");
                            return Ok(dict);
                        }

                        dict.Add(key: "success", value: false);
                        dict.Add(key: "message", value: "Card No must be 7 digit.");
                        return Ok(dict);                            


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();                   

                    dict.Add(key: "success", value: false);
                    dict.Add(key: "message", value: ex.Message);
                    return Ok(dict);

                }
            }

        }
        dict.Add(key: "success", value: false);
        dict.Add(key: "message", value: "Authorized not permitted.");
        return Ok(dict);           
    }
```

Comment: Please share the some information related to the code

Comment: I added the api code here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's work on the assumption. There might be 2 different scenarios.

**General Concepts to keep in mind:**

1. Asynchronous API endpoints
2. Rate limits handling
3. Concurrency control i.e. every time you call an API it opens a WebClient Task, and CPU has limited Threadpools. If you exhaust all of them then the possibility is that your computer could crash, no response, task failure and cancellation.

**Let's discuss the scenarios.**

**Scenario 1**

1. You have an API endpoint and you are calling it from some another Application.
2. You are calling it in parallel/concurrent

*The API endpoint should be implemented like:*

`public async Task<IHttpActionResult> YourAPIMethod()
{
    //The wait able processing
}`

*The critical part is the calling mechanism.* It should be broken in chunk which are processed efficiently. For that you can use `Task.Factory` or `Parallel.Task Library`. Don't rush on creating the tasks in a loop.

Let say I have to call an api-endpoint simultaneously 100 times. I have to design a mechanism to do that. I cannot just simply go and create 100 tasks of web request concurrently. The sample logic would be:

*1. Deciding the chunk size to process simultaneously*
*2. Let them process concurrently but in chunk wise*

Let assume I have a CPU which have 4 cores and 16 virtual processors. So the best chunk size is between 4-6 for me. So my code should be like:

```
  var chunk = GetMaxChunkSize();
  Parallel.For(0, 100, new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None, 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = chunk 
    }, () => { 
       //Process the HttpRequest here either using WebClient or HTTPClient
  });
```

Or you can use the Parallel.Foreach with ParallelOptions like

```
 Parallel.Foreach(yourIEnumerableCollection, new ParallelOptions() { CancellationToken = CancellationToken.None, 
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = chunk 
    }, () => { 
       //Process the HttpRequest here either using WebClient or HTTPClient
  });
```

**Scenario 1: Rate limit exceptions on external API's**
Or if you wish to use the more general Task.Factory for calling the API then there will be some more effort for you. You have to `Skip()` and `Take()` from the particular collection. Adding them in the task list of chunk size. Processing that task List and then moving on the next iteration. The sudo-code is as

```
var chunk = GetChunkSize(); //Finding chunk size
var iterator = 1; // helpful in building our logic
var lstMaxSize = Collection.Count(); // Calculation the collection length
List<Task> taskCollection = new List<Task>(); // the completed task collection
Task[] processingArray = new Task[chunk]; //initialize the new Array of the chunk size

foreach(var item in collection)
{

   if(iterator == chunk){  //if iterator value is equal to our chunk
      Task.WaitAll(processingArray); //wait the queued task to complete
      taskCollection.AddRange(processingArray.ToList()); //copy the queued task in main list 
      iterator = 1; //re-initialize the iterator
      processingArray = new Task[chunk]; //re-initialize the processingArray
   }

   var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
      //Same call the API endpoint here
   });  

   processingArray[iterator++] = task; //adding the task in the processingArray

}

if(iterator < chunk) //Case where our processingArray have some remaining task and the loop is completed
{
   Task.WaitAll(processingArray);
   taskCollection.AddRange(processingArray.ToList());
}
```

This is the implementation we use to handle the rate limit exceptions and process the task concurrently and efficiently. The time you learned about the CPU and threadPool then this will be a piece of just implementation for you.